# Issue when install Grunt

Tags: macos, node.js, npm, gruntjs

I get the Following on imac when install grunt

```
sudo npm install grunt-cli -g
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm ERR! TypeError: uid must be an int
npm ERR!     at Object.fs.chown (fs.js:840:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.chown (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-    fs/polyfills.js:131:17)
npm ERR!     at endChown (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:212:12)
npm ERR!     at setProps (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:295:5)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:286:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:94:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.4.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-cli" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /usr
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.5-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.4
```

Please Help me figure out what I am doing wrong here thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using version 0.10.13.

Comment: please explain how do you change version